# How can I get a more recent Firefox in Ubuntu PowerPC?

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, firefox, ubuntu-mate, powerpc

When I tried to update Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04 ppc it wouldn't go above Version 39. When I updated to Ubuntu Mate 16.04, it updayted for a while and then got 'stuck' at Version 47 while other architectures got up to Version 58. Is there any way of getting a more recent one? I recently downloaded Firefox ESR Version 52 from a Debian repo and installed it using GDebi and this opens but is very laggy. Earler versions couldn't cope with Trello while TenFourFox runs it fine in Mac OSX Leopard on the same machine. A 2005 15" Powerbook 1.67GHz. Now 13 years old and still going strong.

Readouts from terminal:

```
    :~$ type -a firefox
    firefox is /usr/bin/firefox
    :~$ apt-cache policy firefox
     firefox:
      Installed: 47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
      Candidate: 47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
      Version table:
     *** 47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
      500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main  powerpc Packages
    500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main powerpc Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
    500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main powerpc Packages
   :~$ type -a firefox-esr
   firefox-esr is /usr/bin/firefox-esr
   :~$ apt-cache policy firefox-esr
   firefox-esr:
   Installed: 52.6.0esr-1~deb8u1
   Candidate: 52.6.0esr-1~deb8u1
   Version table:
   *** 52.6.0esr-1~deb8u1 100
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: If you Ubuntu version is `12.04.5`, then you should be receveing updates for Firefox, otherwise, you have an End of Life release.

Comment: Try compiling from source (if there's no other way): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion/MozillaBuilds#Manual_Installation

Comment: It is 12.04.5 and is getting other updates, just stuck with some older Firefox. It isn't giving error messages or hassling me to update Firefox but it isn't compatible with some modern sites and probably isn't very secure.

Comment: I upgraded to Ubuntu Mate 16.04 to get Firefox 47. It is still stuck on 47 to this day. All the more recent versions won't build on this platform.

Comment: Have you tried using the Trello command line tool in Ubuntu Mate 16.04? To install it run this command: `sudo snap install so-trello`

Comment: It's a 13 year old computer with a deprecated CPU arch. I'm surprised the hardware still works!

Comment: Still running a supported OS until next year. Apple built them well and it was an expensive machine back in the day. Still nice to use as long as I don't try to stream video!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `type -a firefox` and `apt-cache policy firefox`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Official Ubuntu packages

According to the Ubuntu package website, `powerpc` builds for the `firefox` package provide the following versions:

- [Ubuntu 12.04 provides Firefox 39.0.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/firefox#pdownload)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 provides Firefox 47.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/firefox#pdownload)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 provides Firefox 47.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/firefox#pdownload)

If you want to use the official Ubuntu packages, switch to 14.04 or 16.04 to get 47.0.